# Can a workflow be associated to a folder without custom code?

Tags: workflow, 2007, folder

My client has a document library that contains a folder for each "case" they are working on. These "case" folders contain various documents related to the case. They would like to be able to add a workflow to this folder and route it for approval. Is it possible to do this in SharePoint 2007 without custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge, but I believe you can in SP 2010 with the Document Set functionality, [Document Sets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, at this point, I'm pretty sure that it is not possible either. I wasn't aware of Document Sets and they look like a good solution to this problem. We'll be moving to SP2010 soon, so I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: I can guarantee that workflows on Document Sets in SP2010 will do exactly what you want as that's how I used them recently for a customer. Document sets are basically a content type based folder that contains other permitted content types. The workflows then run against these.

You do get some nice dashboard functionality with Document Sets, but you can't keep them if you want to move the entire set to a records centre, or declare the set as a record.

Worth looking at tho.